# Notification Android не работает на старых версиях

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Падает приложение и не показывеются уведомление под андроид 2.3.7, на андроиде 4.2.2 и 4.0.4 все нормально, как переделать этот скрипт?

ADB на телефоне глючит поэтому логи прислать не могу.

```
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("ТЕСТ")
            .setContentText("ТЕСТ 1"); // Текст уведомления

    Notification notification = builder.build();

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    notificationManager.notify(101, notification);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) появился с 11  API, а вы запускаете на 10 API который ничего не знает об этом классе. 
Попробуйте использовать [NotificationCompat.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html).

Comment: Не работает, смог логи достать

Comment: at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.enqueueNotificationWithTag(INotificationManager.java:274) at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:111)

Comment: at android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompatEclair.postNotification(NotificationManagerCompatEclair.java:30) at android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat$ImplEclair.postNotification(NotificationManagerCompat.java:152) at android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat.notify(NotificationM

Comment: anagerCompat.java:225) at android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat.notify(NotificationM
at ux.uchat.Dialog_sil.StatusBar(Dialog_sil.java:101)
at ux.uchat.Dialog_sil.StartUchat(Dialog_sil.java:550)
at ux.uchat.Start_UChat$1StartAct.onPostExecute(Start_UChat.java:76)
at ux.uchat.Start_UChat$1StartAct.onPostExecute(Start_UChat.java:29)

Comment: Отправил частями так как форум ваще х, не желает отправлять много символов

Comment: public void StatusBar(){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("ТЕСТ")
                .setContentText("ТЕСТ 1"); // Текст уведомления
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, еще необходимо вызвать setContentIntent